# Strange problem with light through glass

Tags: transparency, lighting, glass

After having worked with vray for a long time, I recently started Blender and I am having trouble with glass and lights. As you can see the light sources show as spheres through some of the glass, which is obviously not desirable. Stranger thing is through other glass they look correct. **Both glasses have same material**. I don`t understand what might be the reason.

[image: front glasses]
[image: side glasses]

[image: render result]

[image: In viewport all lights appear as spheres]
[image: glass shader]

[image: data properties][image: object properties]

[image: inside render with transmission on]
[image: inside viewport - transmission on]

Comment: Does replacing the Maximum node with a simple value change anything?

Comment: I would suspect if seen through different windows at different angles that the reason for the different behaviour is found in the windows... have they different thicknesses? Have some of them no thickness at all and are just simple faces?

Comment: The reason why you see the light sources so big is that their radius is set to 35 cm and _Transmission_ visibility is enabled. This means, through transmissive material you will see the light as sphere with a radius of 35 cm. The same would happen from inside the cabin because _Glossy_ visibility is enabled and the glass has a glossy surface. Of course you could turn that off as well, the problem will be this also removes reflective highlights on glossy surfaces.

Comment: @joachim I tried a simple value; thencutting off `light path` and `maximum` and clamping `maximum` with no effect

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I checked the windows, they have same characteristics; adding images

Comment: What I can't see in the screenshots is the _Outliner_: are the side windows maybe hidden in the _3D Viewport_ and only visible in the real rendering? Apart from that, the lighting in both images looks quite different so I wonder what other settings are changed between viewport and render. And what render engine are you actually using, _Cycles_ or _Eevee_ or _Vray_ which you mention in the question?

Comment: Anyway, since the desired effect is not to see the lights you have to disable the _Transmission_ visibility. Although you might not like it, as long as it's enabled it is the "correct" way that you see the light as spheres.

Comment: I will check now all that is different between viewport and render and the scenes (outliner). Disabling transmission doesn`t have any effect though; I am attaching both views from inside; this time outside lights look as spheres, inside ones are OK

Comment: All renders and render preview are Cycles

Comment: Of course renders from inside will show outside lights as spheres - because you see them through the glass window, a transmissive object. The lights are set to be visible for _Transmission_. Have you disabled it for all lights?

Comment: I think I misread before; yes, you are right; when I disable Transmission, it's all OK (apart from the fact that the bulb doesn't look as if it is on). 
You are also right about the reason between the front and side windows; different settings in the Outliner. 
When I change the math node value to `Power` instead of `Maximum` it works with Glossy and Transmission enabled (but I don't have reflections on the glass from the lights). I think although it's a bit difficult to comprehend, I should work on the `light path` node a lot more. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not technical enough at all to understand this. But from a real perspective, looking at a light through a window doesn't really affect the look of the light source. So why do you guys think that behavior is correct in this scenario?

Comment: It seems to me that it has something to do with how Cycles handles ray tracing. With v-ray this was not a problem.

Comment: I finally found a more or less acceptable solution. I duplicate the point light (at the same exact location). I put first one into a translucent container (like a bulb or a lamp shade) and reduce its radius to fit inside the container; adjust power and color accordingly, just how I want it to look (through glass and directly). Second light can be any size or color, as I disable its ray visibility through properties tab (except 'diffuse' and 'volume'). So geometrically only the first light is seen, but the second (not visible) light is the one that illuminates.